# How do I create a browser Interface or mini browser which will use very low amount of RAM?

Tags: visual-c++

I only need to keep a page open within that browser which will auto reload at every 35 seconds to keep the connection active with my ISP. I have tried creating a Windows Form Application using Visual C++ 2008, but that seems inefficient in memory management. After running it 10 Mins the RAM use goes above 35 MB. I don't want that. I expect RAM usage to stay below 10 MB !

How do i create a browser interface which will minimize the RAM usage but serve my purpose of keeping my connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a browser. You only need a periodic network connection to the server. In programming libraries, this is called a 'socket' . Start your research there.

Comment: Socket wont do what I need here. The page is not entirely a "KEEP ALIVE CONNECTION" kind of page ! It's a login page (\client.jsp). After login it needs to be kept open, other wise after a while I will be logged out from my ISP's server ! The JSP page communicates with some kind of "Servelet" which periodically checks for If I'm logged in or not. The ISP is not providing any software. They are told to keep a browser on with that page logged in.

Comment: A browser like Firefox takes quite a bit of RAM (50 + for that single page). Therefore I want to create a simplistic browser which can serve that page without using that much RAM.

Comment: I was able to create a browser interface using "Real Studio" by implementing "HtmlViewer" module, but with that Im seeing this strange URL after three fore reloads : res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm#http://172.30.60.1:9090/ !  Do you have any Idea what this is ?! I did not saw this before when I was using the Interface created using WebBrowser Control in VS C++ 2008 !